# Hibernate OneToMany mappedby inserts duplicate records when saved

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2, hibernate-mapping

I have a simple oneToMany relationship provided in Parent and corresponding ManyToOne in the Chile Entity class:

Parent:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FormExtraInfo")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="form_container_id")
public class Form extends Container {

private List<Reason> reasons = new ArrayList<Reason>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy="form",cascade={javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL},orphanRemoval=true)
@Cascade(value={CascadeType.ALL})
public List<Reason> getReasons() {
    return reasons;
}

public void setReasons(List<Reason> reasons) {
    this.reasons = reasons;
}

public void addReason(Reason reason) {
    if (this.reasons == null) {
        this.reasons = new ArrayList<Reason>();
    }

    this.reasons.add(reason);
}
```

}

Child class:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="Container_id")
public Form getForm() {
    return form;
}

public void setForm(Form form) {
    this.form = form;
}
```

Action class:

```
//Set the reasons
    String[] reasonStatus = strutsForm.getMultiValueProperty(REASON_STATUS);
    String[] reasonText = strutsForm.getMultiValueProperty(REASON_TEXT);

    List<Reason> reasons = new ArrayList<Reason>();     

    logger.debug("form container ID : " + form.getId() +". # of Reasons for this form: "+ reasonText.length);

    for (int i = 0; i < reasonText.length; i++) {
        Reason r = new Reason();
        r.setComment(reasonText[i]);
        r.setStatusTypeCode(reasonStatus[i]);
        r.setForm(form); 
        reasons.add(r);
    }
    form.setReasons(reasons);
```

Example case:
Status_code   Reason_text
abc           abc1
xyz           xyz1

save the form:
Status_code   Reason_text
abc           abc1
xyz           xyz1
abc           abc1
xyz           xyz1

With any operation : New insert or delete or update, it first duplicates the old data to the DB and then the operation that I performed.

Comment: Do you really need List<Reason> to be a list? Hibernate suggests using Set<Reason>... Is form a new object or did you retrieve it from the database?

Comment: Thank you for your help! Form is being retrieved from Database. Each form can have multiple Reasons. form and Reasons are two different tables in Database. I tried Set, did not work!

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the cascade clause for this

```
@Cascade (value={CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE,CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN})
```

Take a look at my blog post on mapping one-to-many http://arecordon.blogspot.com.ar/2013/05/hibernate-mapping-associations-one-to_20.html

Comment: CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN is marked as deprecated. But this suggestion also did not help!

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a Set instead of a List; then, try changing the collection to a Set and make sure you overwrite equals() hashCode() as specified in here:

https://community.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsAndHashCode?_sscc=t

Also, remove the duplicated cascaded, you ca use:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="form",cascade={javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL},orphanRemoval=true)
```

or

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="form")
@Cascade(value={CascadeType.ALL, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN})
```